# How to model blazar light curves

Tags: quasars, light-curve, modeling, flare, blazars

I have SED data spanning over a couple of days and I'm able to find the parameters of the SED (R, B, break energy,...) using least squares method. My question is how to model light curves (with t_acc, t_esc, ...) from the data that I have.

Example of what I want to do is in the image below (the black dots are actual observed data and the red line is the model that I want to create):

[image: examples of blazar light curves]

Comment: Have you had any luck? If you think you've found a solution you are welcome to post an answer to your own question; if you've made some progress then adding some details here might accelerate an answer.